# Problem Dagger Cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method, When I use @Named annotation

Tags: java, android, kotlin, dagger-2

I am facing a problem when I put the @Named annotation in the AppModule and here is my code, The problem appears only when I add the @Named annotation to both the 'AppModule' and the 'IdentityRepository', but when I remove it from both everything is fine

> Note that I have to use @Named because I want  to create a second
>   function with the same DataType in the same Module

```
@Module
object AppModule {
...

    @Provides
    @JvmStatic
    @Singleton
    @Named("NOT_AUTH_IDENTITY_SERVICE")
    fun provideIdentityService(retrofit: Retrofit): IdentityService =
        retrofit.create(IdentityService::class.java)
}
```

and when I use it the IdentityRepository

```
class IdentityRepository @Inject constructor() {

    @Inject
    @Named("NOT_AUTH_IDENTITY_SERVICE")
    lateinit var identityService: IdentityService
...
}
```

I am facing this error

> error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] solutions IdentityService cannot be
>   provided without an @Provides-annotated method. public abstract
>   interface AppComponent extends
>   dagger.android.AndroidInjector
>   { ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following [the documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html#annotation-use-site-targets):

> When you're annotating a property or a primary constructor parameter, there are multiple Java elements which are generated from the corresponding Kotlin element, and therefore multiple possible locations for the annotation in the generated Java bytecode. To specify how exactly the annotation should be generated.

when using `Named` providers with Kotlin you have to explicitly annotate the **field** with the `@field` annotation:

```
class IdentityRepository @Inject constructor() {

    @Inject
    @field:Named("NOT_AUTH_IDENTITY_SERVICE")
    lateinit var identityService: IdentityService
...
}
```

Or you could just move the property to a constructor, since you are also using constructor injection:

```
class IdentityRepository @Inject constructor(
    @Named("NOT_AUTH_IDENTITY_SERVICE") val identityService: IdentityService
) {
...
}
```

Comment: Can I have a connection with you man, I am new in dagger and maybe I need some help if you don't mind

Comment: @A.Albrg We can discuss any other problems you are facing in chat: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202206/discussion-between-jsamol-and-a-albrg